# More efficient way to write this script

Tags: excel, vba

I am printing a lot of excel charts using vba. At this point I have about ~35 sheets I print from, so I'm wondering if there's a script that is easier to modify than the one I am currently working with.

```
Sheets("Euro Graph").Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
ActiveChart.PageSetup.RightHeader = "nominal LCU"
ActiveChart.PageSetup.RightFooter = "&D  &T"
ActiveChart.PageSetup.CenterFooter = "&A"
ActiveChart.PageSetup.LeftFooter = "&Z&F"
Selection.Width = 921
Selection.Left = 23
Selection.Top = 61
Selection.Height = 550
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
```

So this works just fine. For each chart I want to print I first select the sheet, and then activate the chart I want to print by referring to its chart number. Is there an efficient way to change any chart printing specs (like changing the header/footer) without manually having to change every block of code that I use for each chart?

Edit: I could remove a lot the lines and just have

```
Sheets("Euro Graph").Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.PageSetup.RightHeader = "nominal LCU"
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
```

But I would still like to be able to change "nominal LCU" and have it affect all my code.

Comment: Is there more than 1 chart per sheet? How do you determine the `RightHeader`, which seems to be the only variable text? Are the PlotArea dimensions always the same? \

Comment: Yes. I have about 3-4 charts per sheet. The RightHeader is the tricky one, since a sheet will usually have 3 charts, one with nominal LCU, real USD, and nominal USD. I have a module for each type of chart. And the plot area dimensions are always the same.

Comment: Does either the chart Index or the chart title consistently indicate which of the three types it is? For example nominal LCU is always chart 1, or always named or titled something? (If not, you should consider making it so). If so, then it will be pretty easy to code. Actually, if you want to stick with three modules, I can do it now.

Comment: Actually, I just realized you have to have 3 routines, because the headers change.

Comment: No I could do it if it was consistent chart numbers. But I would say there is practically no pattern. Some nominal LCU are number 1 or they could be number 6. The title names are consistent. It goes:         "Area Code: Country Name, LN Scale, Nominal LCU x 10^9, Millions of Persons"

Comment: Nominal LCU is interchangeable with real USD, etc.

Comment: If it helps I would name the charts `chtNominalLCU`, etc. Charts on different worksheets can have the same name. This can be done from the Layout tab. In programming it's like `ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Name = "chtNominalLCU"`. A VBA array could could store the chart names and corresponding headers, or this information could be in a hidden worksheet.

Comment: Do you have this block of code for every chart then?  Could you put all of that into a `Sub` and make the information that changes variables such as the Header, Sheet Name, and Chart Name.  Then just go `PrintReport(Header, SheetName, ChartName)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only somewhat tested, but it should show you how to loop through the worksheets with chartobjects, and how to identify an LCU chartobject:

```
Sub SetLCUCharts()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim chtObject As Excel.ChartObject
Dim cht As Excel.Chart

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
        For Each chtObject In ws.ChartObjects
            If InStr(chtObject.Name, "LCU") > 0 Then
                Set cht = ws.ChartObjects(1).Chart
                With cht
                    .PageSetup.RightHeader = "nominal LCU"
                    .PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
                End With
            End If
        Next chtObject
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: this should do the job, thanks! the InStr() function will help me a lot.